# Using PHP in $html = sting?

Tags: php

I have the following code which displays currently a YouTube video via html embed code.

```
 <?php
if ( function_exists( 'wpmudev_ppw_html' ) ) {
$html = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-uiN9z5tqhg?wmode=transparent&" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'; // html code to be protected (required)
$id = 1; // An optional unique id if you are using the function more than once on a single page
$description = 'video'; // Optional description of the protected content
$price = '1.50'; // Optional price for a single view. If not set, price set in the post will be applied. If that is not set either, Unit Price in the Global Settings will be used.
echo wpmudev_ppw_html( $html, $id, $description, $price );
}
?>
```

I would like to remove the YouTube iFrame and have it display the following code instead.

```
<img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="<?php the_field('macro_map'); ?>" />
```

However, the PHP code in the $html= line causes a syntax error when done like so...

```
$html = '<img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="<?php the_field('macro_map'); ?>" />';
```

First, is it even possible for this to work. If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have `<?php ?>` inside `<?php ?>` tags. You will need to remove the nested tags and use a `.` to concatenate the string and return of the function.

```
$html = '<img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="' . the_field('macro_map') . '" />';
```

Comment: Well, that makes sense! :) lol Your code works, but it's just outputting the image URL, not the actual image. Hmm

Comment: @user2612111 what does `the_field('macro_map')` return?

Comment: Its a custom wordpress field returning an image URL

Comment: A custom field made using Advanced Custom Fields

Comment: @user2612111 If that returns only a url and not `HTML` it should be a full image, add `print_r($html)` just after it and see what that outputs.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference either. And yes, it is a simple URL output, no HTML. It works fine with my 2nd example above, but not with your suggestion. This is what the html output looks like with your example:

' 
"

 http://www.runningalpha.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/map-sample.jpg"

<img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="">
<img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="">

'